# Can't adjust input when hovering over a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `div` that's hidden and can only be shown when it's hovering over another `div`. The hidden `div` is an input function that's a test on another project; doesn't do anything, just to make sure it's functionally working.

I'm halfway completed with my code: the `div volume-adjuster` with the input function becomes available when you hover over a `div volume-button`.

The problem is that I can't work the slider. It available but you can't touch it.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/openbayou/pen/NjGGaR)

Full code:

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .volume-contain {
      width: 200px
    }
    
    .volume-adjuster {
      float: left;
      visibility: hidden
    }
    
    .volume-button {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      float: right
    }
    
    .volume-button .button {
      float: right;
      width: 40px;
      background: black;
      height: 40px
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="volume-contain">
    <div class="volume-adjuster"><input type="range" min="0" max="15" value="3" id="fader"></div>
    <div class="volume-button">
      <div class="button"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.volume-button').hover(
        function() {
          $('.volume-adjuster').css({
            "visibility": "visible"
          });
          $('.volume-button').css({
            "width": "200px"
          });
          $('.volume-button').css({
            "margin-top": "-22px"
          });
        },
        function() {
          $('.volume-adjuster').css({
            "visibility": "hidden"
          });
          $('.volume-button').css({
            "width": "40px"
          });
          $('.volume-button').css({
            "margin-top": "0"
          });
        }
      );
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: As note, remember that you can do $element.css({ property1: 'value1', property2: 'value2' /* , etc... */})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change a few things in your code(mainly css) and you are good to go

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.volume-button').hover(
    function() {
      $('.volume-adjuster').css({
        "display": "block"
      });

    },
    function() {
      $('.volume-adjuster').css({
        "display": "none"
      });

    }
  );
});
```

```css
.volume-contain {
  width: 200px;
}

.volume-adjuster {
  float: left;
  display:none;

}

.volume-button {
  float: right;
  
}

.volume-button .button {
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  background: black;
  height: 40px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="volume-contain">
 
  <div class="volume-button">
   <div class="volume-adjuster"><input type="range" min="0" max="15" value="3" id="fader"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to bind this with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events on parent element as z-index will need position property to be set you can handle it like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.volume-contain').mouseenter(
 function () {
   $('.volume-adjuster').css({"visibility":"visible"});
 }
);
  $('.volume-contain').mouseleave(
  function () {
   $('.volume-adjuster').css({"visibility":"hidden"});
 });
});
```

[CODEPEN DEMO HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NjGvRw)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you set `.volume-button` element to `width: 200px` when it is hovered. It will step over your input element and you can not click on your input but you still see it.  [Chiller comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43468849/4254681) is a clearly soulution. But if you still want to use your code, you should make some small change like this:
- Add hover function for input:

```
$('.volume-adjuster').hover(function() {
    $('.volume-adjuster').css({
      "visibility": "visible"
    });
  })
```

- Change the width of `.volume-button` element down to 100 in its hover function:

```
$('.volume-button').css({
        "width": "100px"
      });
```

You can see the compele code [here](http://codepen.io/duannx/pen/NjGaPE?editors=1010).